# Posting JSON data using PHP HttpRequest class

Tags: php, json, httprequest

Here is a JSON i have which i want to POST to a URL using `HTTP_METH_POST`:

```
{
    "request_token": "dSMXgdfHOeNflvk0xo3BYA",
    "user[display_name]": "CNN",
    "user[email]": "CliENT_EMAIL@DOMAIN.com"
}
```

so if i use `addQueryData` method then will i be able to post that to the URL as a Json Data or is there any other steps i have to do to send a JSON data using `HttpRequest` class ??

Comment: I've never used the HttpRequest class but looking at the docs, it seem addQueryData expects an associative array that is turn into a post request. What you most likely want to do is use [setBody](http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.setbody.php) instead

Comment: Also make sure to set the method to POST using [setMethod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.setmethod.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you have run your JSON through json_encode to turn it into a string then that is all you need before you post the data.

Comment: Yep obviously i have to json encode, So it means that i don't need to add any content type like that ? `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: No you don't need a special content type for posting JSON data.

Comment: Yes, the other side might care (it might affect how its processed), you should set the Content-Type with [setContentType](http://www.php.net/manual/en/httprequest.setcontenttype.php).